# Nodejs: Recall function in catch block returns undefined in a try-catch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an async function in a class that has a try-catch. When the try encounters an error, I would like to recall the function to reattempt.

My current implementation successfully recalls the function in the catch block, but if the sequential attempts succeed, the returned result is always `undefined`.

Code:

```
class Extractor {

    constructor(item) {
        this.item = item
    }

    async start() {

        try {
            let results = await someApiCallPromise()
            this.item.moreData = results
            return this.item //<== Upon sequential recall from catch, it always return undefined

        } catch (err) {
            if (err == "someError") {
                await this.start() // <== this.start() recalls successfully
            } else {
                //Other error handling method
            }
        } 
    }
}

//Usage
let item = {
    param1: '1',
    param2: '2'
}

let extractor = new Extractor(item)
extractor.start()
.then(item => {
    console.log(item) // <== Always return undefined if recalled from catch block
})
```

How do I return `this.item` if it suceeds from the recall in the catch block?

Answer (score 2):

You must `return` your recursive call in `catch`:
`return this.start()`
Since you are `returning` a promise (call to async function) there is no need to `await` on that.